# Javascript entire div link WITH target="_blank"

Tags: javascript, html

I have set up a div with a button link. I have my javascript set up so if someone clicks anyway in the div, it will use the link text. Here's my current code:

```
 jQuery(function($){
 $(".entire-div-link").click(function() {
 window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
 return false;
 });
 });
```

This works awesome, but the links still open in the current tab, and not in a new tab like I'd like. Is there an easy code correction I can use?

Comment: [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: If you have control over the HTML and if the contents do not contain any other interactive elements (i.e. buttons, links, form controls), you can just wrap everything with the `<a href="..." target="_blank">`, no JS required. Just make sure you give it `display:block`.

Comment: @Pointy `window.open` will open new browser window instead of tab

Comment: @EugeneTsakh well it depends on the browser configuration. In no case is it possible to control whether a new "window" is a separate OS window or a new tab in an existing window; that's ultimately user-controlled.

Comment: This is jquery.

Comment: Why not just `$(this).find("a").click();` (instead of changing the `location`) and let the link do what it should do normally?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `a` tag as a block instead of div:

```
//css
.block-link {
  display: block;
}

// html
<a class="block-link" target="_blank">
  ...
</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kjugdpnf/

Comment: This will not work if the div has more than one line of data and the `a` tag is just one liner (or a word).

Comment: @NimitShah take a look on css section. If you will add `display: block;` style to the link it will become block like a div

Comment: but `.entire-div-link` is not for `a` tag. its for the `div` which contains one `a` tag with href.

Comment: @NimitShah take a look on html section I've assigned this class to `a` tag. )
Added jsfiddle with an example

Comment: Updated class name to avoid confusing

Answer (score -1):

Try `window.open` instead of `window.location`.

https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/t4wnsrkh/

Comment: `window.open` should not be used as this task could be done with CSS only

Comment: You can not add entire data in the `a` tag.. its not a good practice buddy.

Comment: No, I can and it's a common practice.

Answer (score -1):

Just do this, it's way shorter with plain JS:

```
document.querySelector(".entire-div-link").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  window.open = "URL HERE"
})
```

As it was already mentioned, whether `window.open` will open a new tab OR a new window, depends solely on the user's browser configuration.